# How to delete text that does not start with a certain amount of numbers in dataframe column

Tags: r, string, multiple-columns, data-cleaning

I have this:

```
col1
1234HO
9535KU
4532SP
1
hello
xyz
1206
9530OK
23
8524US
```

And I need it to be this:

```
col1     col2    col3
1234HO   1234    HO
9535KU   9535    KU
4532SP   4532    SP
                       #these rows still need to be there


1206     1206          #keep in mind that I still want to keep this if there is 4 numbers
9530OK   9530    OK

8524US   8524    US
```

I tried removing it manually, but it's a bit too much work.
I am not sure how to make a function that says "delete all text that does not start with 4 numbers". I would only know how to do it if they were all the same numbers, but they can be any numbers.

Comment: You can do this easily with a regexp, did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach with very low level of regex.

### Input

```
# your df
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
col1
1234HO
9535KU
4532SP
1
hello
xyz
1206
9530OK
23
8524US")
```

### Empty rows

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(col2 = str_extract(col1, "^[0-9]{4,}"), 
              col3 = str_extract(col1, "[A-Z].*$"),
              col3 = replace_na(col3, ""),
              across(everything(), ~ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]{4}", col1), .x, print(""))))

     col1 col2 col3
1  1234HO 1234   HO
2  9535KU 9535   KU
3  4532SP 4532   SP
4                  
5                  
6                  
7    1206 1206     
8  9530OK 9530   OK
9                  
10 8524US 8524   US
```

### Rows as NA

```
# if you want them to be filled with NA
df %>% mutate(col2 = str_extract(col1, "^[0-9]{4,}"), 
              col3 = str_extract(col1, "[A-Z].*$"),
              across(everything(), ~ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]{4}", col1), .x, NA)))

     col1 col2 col3
1  1234HO 1234   HO
2  9535KU 9535   KU
3  4532SP 4532   SP
4    <NA> <NA> <NA>
5    <NA> <NA> <NA>
6    <NA> <NA> <NA>
7    1206 1206 <NA>
8  9530OK 9530   OK
9    <NA> <NA> <NA>
10 8524US 8524   US
```

Comment: this deletes the other rows. I still want to keep the other rows that have 1, hello, xyz etc, I just want the values to be empty on those rows.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: And I see that if I just want to replace col1, col2 and col3 with NA, I just replace "everything()" with c(col1, col2, col3).

Comment: Replace `everything()` with `col1:col3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::separate` and then `filter`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  separate(col1, into = c("num", "text"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", remove = F) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("[A-Za-z]", num) & nchar(num) > 3)

    col1  num text
1 1234HO 1234   HO
2 9535KU 9535   KU
3 4532SP 4532   SP
4   1206 1206 <NA>
5 9530OK 9530   OK
6 8524US 8524   US
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  col1 = c("1234HO","9535KU",
           "4532SP","1","hello","xyz","1206","9530OK","23",
           "8524US")
)

df %>% 
  separate(col1, into=str_c("col", 2:3), sep="(?<=\\d{4})",
     remove = F, fill = "right") %>% filter(!is.na(col3))

#>     col1 col2 col3
#> 1 1234HO 1234   HO
#> 2 9535KU 9535   KU
#> 3 4532SP 4532   SP
#> 4   1206 1206     
#> 5 9530OK 9530   OK
#> 6 8524US 8524   US
```